# Parallax effect within a modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parallax, modal-window

I'm creating a bootstrap one page website that contains some pop up modal windows and wish to use a parallax img effect within the modal windows. Wondering if anyone has done this before as I can't seem to find any solutions that work within the modal windows themselves??

Comment: have you tried modifying wht you have found to work with these so called "modal windows"

Comment: I've tried implementing several parallax image "kits" as such, but can't get them to work in the pop up windows, only on the main body of the website.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle with what you expert so far?

Comment: here is a JS fiddle explaining what I'm trying to do???

https://jsfiddle.net/GG9Sa/1382/

Comment: Can anybody help that knows a lot about integrating parallax effects into a website????